# pandas reading .csv files

Tags: python-2.7, parsing, csv, python-3.4

I have a small script to read and print a .csv file using pandas generated from MS Excel.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('./2010-11.csv')
print(data)
```

now this script runs in Python 2.7.8 but in Python 3.4.1 gives the following
error. Any ideas why this might be so? Thanks in advance for any help with this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "proc_csv_0-0.py", line 3, in <module>
    data = pd.read_csv('./2010-11.csv')
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 474, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 260, in _read
    return parser.read()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 721, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1170, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 769, in pandas.parser.TextReader.read (pandas/parser.c:7566)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 791, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas/parser.c:7806)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 866, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_rows (pandas/parser.c:8639)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 973, in pandas.parser.TextReader._convert_column_data (pandas/parser.c:9950)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 1033, in pandas.parser.TextReader._convert_tokens (pandas/parser.c:10737)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 1130, in pandas.parser.TextReader._convert_with_dtype (pandas/parser.c:12141)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 1150, in pandas.parser.TextReader._string_convert (pandas/parser.c:12355)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 1382, in pandas.parser._string_box_utf8 (pandas/parser.c:17679)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc9 in position 4: unexpected end of data
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python3, when `pd.read_csv` is passed a file path (as opposed to a file buffer) it decodes the contents with the `utf-8` codec by default.<sup>1</sup> It appears your CSV file is using a different encoding. Since it was generated by MS Excel, it *might* be cp-1252:

```
In [25]: print('\xc9'.decode('cp1252'))
É

In [27]: import unicodedata as UDAT   
In [28]: UDAT.name('\xc9'.decode('cp1252'))
Out[28]: 'LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E WITH ACUTE'
```

The error message

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc9
```

says that `'\xc9'.decode('utf-8')` raises a UnicodeDecodeError.

The above shows byte 0xc9 can be decoded with `cp1252`. It remains to be seen if the rest of the file can also be decoded with `cp1252`, and if it produces the desired result.

Unfortunately, given only a file, there is no surefire way to tell what
encoding (if any) was used. It depends entirely on the program used to generate
the file.

If `cp1252` is the right encoding, then to load the file into a DataFrame use

```
data = pd.read_csv('./2010-11.csv', encoding='cp1252')
```

---

<sup>1</sup> When `pd.read_csv` is passed a buffer, the buffer could have been opened with `encoding` already set:

```
# Python3
with open('/tmp/test.csv', 'r', encoding='cp1252') as f:
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    print(df)
```

in which case `pd.read_csv` will not attempt to decode since the buffer `f` is already supplying decoded strings.

Comment: Spot on, thanks. Any idea why the script work in py_2.7 without the encoding but not in py_3.4 ?

Comment: In Python2.7, `pd.read_csv` seems to leave the data as bytes. In Python3, `pd.read_csv` tries to decode the bytes.