# odo converting data between csv and mysql

Tags: windows, python-3.x, csv, pandas, odo

When converting one of the `.csv's` to a `pd.DataFrame` using the python `odo` module I receive a `TypeError`

```
    TypeError: Cannot cast array from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') 
               according to the rule 'safe'
```

The code that works for other `csv's`

```
# csv table file name
csvNm = 'table.csv'

# convert mysql table to csv
odo_csv = odo(tstConn.connect_string + '::' + tbl , csvNm)

# convert csv to pandas 
odo_df = odo(odo_csv , pd.DataFrame)
```

**Here is what I tried so far to no avail:**

```
import pandas as pd
from odo import odo, resource, discover, convert

odo_csv=odo(tstConn.connect_string + '::' + tbl , csvNm)
csv=resource(csvNm)
ds=discover(csv)

# Convert csv to pandas
odo_df = odo(odo_csv , pd.DataFrame, dshape=ds)
```

and this:

```
odo_df = odo(odo_csv , pd.DataFrame, casting='unsafe')
```

**Update 1**
It looks like I neglected the most obvious hint in this error

```
pandas\parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._convert_tokens (pandas\parser.c:11816)()
```

Leading to encoding issues in Windows [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31515626/pandas-reading-csv-files).
But neither this:

```
odo_df = odo(odo_csv , pd.DataFrame, encoding=odo_csv.encoding)
```

or this work

```
odo_df = odo(odo_csv , pd.DataFrame, encoding='cp1252')
```

This inelegant way (for my use-case) taken from [pandas-reading-csv-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31515626/pandas-reading-csv-files) (same link as above)

```
# Python3
with open('/tmp/test.csv', 'r', encoding='cp1252') as f:
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    print(df)
```

Not sure what to try next, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that works is:

```
import pandas as pd
from odo import odo, resource, discover, convert

# convert mysql to csv
odo_csv=odo(raw_dbConn.connect_string + '::' + tblName , csvNm, header=True)

# Get odo resource aka sqlalchemy.Table instance
resc=resource(raw_dbConn.connect_string + '::' + tblName )

# Discover the resc
ds=discover(resc)

# Convert csv to dataframe    
odo_df = odo(odo_csv , pd.DataFrame, dshape=ds ,encoding=odo_csv.encoding)
```

Comment: Funny thing is that 
`with open('/tmp/test.csv', 'r', encoding='cp1252') as f:
    df = pd.read_csv(f)` is about a minute faster for a df with a shape of (114,690,970, 5)